# What should be the correct Indirect form of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence in a high school grammar book. What should be the correct Indirect form of this sentence ?

> “So help me, Heaven!” he cried, “I will never 
>   steal again.”

According to me it should be

> He urged the Heaven to help him and swore to never steal again.

OR

> Urging the Heaven to help him, he swore to never steal again.

OR

> He pleaded the Heaven to help him and swore to never steal again.

I am really confused. Please tell what should be the correct answer.

P.S : The book has mentioned this as the correct answer, but I am not at all convinced.

> He called upon Heaven to witness his resolve never to steal again.

And why can I not use the typical indirect exclamatory sentence construct *"He exclaimed with sorrow..."* here ?

Comment: I agree with the book's answer. Compare to *On my mother's grave, I will never steal again.*

Comment: Yeah but doesn't the book's answer tamper a lot with the sentence ? I mean, is it okay to insert so many new words (upon, witness, resolve) just to convert it to indirect form ?

Comment: It's not just the indirect form, it'st he underlying meaning (which is displayed in the direct form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncertainty arises because *"So help me, Heaven"* doesn't really mean anything, so much as it intensifies the rest of what he says.

[This post](http://americancreation.blogspot.com/2012/02/so-help-me-god-what-does-it-mean.html) describes how *So help me god* came to be used as the end of a promise of truthfulness in court.  Essentially:

> The phrase *"so help me God,"* a popular component of grand and petit juror oath statutes, is actually an abbreviated form of the oath, *"So may God help me at the judgment day if I speak true, but if I speak false, then may He withdraw His help from me."*

This is a plausible origin, but not a commonly known one.  *So help me, X* is now used in the US to simply mean *"you better believe I am going to do what I say I am going to do,"* and is not necessarily associated with commitment to good behavior.

Samples of ["*so help me*" being used in less-than holy ways:](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22so%20help%20me%22%20beat%20his%20butt)

Back to your sentence:

> “So help me, Heaven!” he cried, “I will never steal again.”

I don't think it is correct to say that he is asking for assistance in not stealing, but your use of *swore* is good, because it brings in a religious overtone.

My indirect paraphrase would therefore be:

> He emphatically swore that he would never steal again.

That isn't to say that the book is wrong - there are lots of ways to convert any sentence - but I agree with you that they added a little bit of extra interpretation.

Comment: Great answer ! Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot ! :)